# when I set style to gridview line I lost selector

Tags: android, styles, selection, itemselector

I want to list my items in gridview. The grid view connected an adapter. This adapter have a layout xml. then xml is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUrunAd"
        style="@style/gridline"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:text="@string/GrdUrunAd" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMiktar"
        style="@style/gridline"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:text="@string/GrdMiktar" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBirim"
        style="@style/gridline"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:text="@string/GrdBirim" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFiyat"
        style="@style/gridline"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:text="@string/GrdFiyat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTutar"
        style="@style/gridline"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:text="@string/GrdTutar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If care is taken my layout have a style. 
when I set this style my gridview lost selector effect.
when I delete this style my gridview have selector effect.

```
    <style name="gridline" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item> 
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/grdlinebackcolor_white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: remove  `<item name="android:focusable">true</item> <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>` and try

Comment: i did try this but not working it

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is setting the background as a solid colour. Selectors are drawables which are set as the items background

Comment: yes my issue is that. but i haven't a solition.. i try a drawable. i did build a xml shape but not change anything. but i reazlized, selector stay under of my drawables.. but I have no idea about the solution. have you?